# Problem with <svg> not scaling to page width

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a problem with my SVG where I'm trying to "improve" and better separate different sections on my website but this SVG path doesn't want to scale to page width, instead, its size stays fixed.
The svg element does scale, but the path stays the same...
I know there is a way to make it scale properly, can you help me on that?

```css
svg {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" width="100%" height="150" viewBox="800 -50 200 200">
 <path d="M0 107 L220 69 L484 135 L800 82 L800 150 L0 150 Z" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do the same with background and gradient then you want have issue with scaling:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 49%, #000 50%) -80px calc(100% - 20px)/calc(100%/3 + 81px) 80px, 
   linear-gradient(to bottom left , transparent 49%, #000 50%)  50% calc(100% - 20px)/calc(100%/3) 80px, 
   linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 49%, #000 50%) 100% calc(100% - 20px)/calc(100%/3) 50px, 
   linear-gradient(#000, #000) bottom/100% 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Another way with easier code:

```css
body {
  position:relative;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
}
body:after {
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 height:80px;
 right:-80px;
 left:-80px;
 border-bottom:20px solid #000;
 background: 
   linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 49%, #000 50%) left, 
   linear-gradient(to bottom left , transparent 49%, #000 50%) center, 
   linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 49%, #000 50%) right;
  background-size:calc(100%/3) 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Still i need it to be svg because this way doesn't let me do this in page header. Which i can't really explain.

Comment: Sorry I don't see how this is relevant to the question? There is no issue with the background.

Comment: @FalsePride if you explain I will show you how you can do it ;)

Comment: @MSC look at his SVG and my gradient .. I am providing an alternative way yo have the same visual without scaling issue

Comment: because as I'm using it in a high header it also does scale the height. i need the height to be fixed and the width to adjust to the page.

Comment: @FalsePride my code doesn't scale the height, the height is fixed and only the width is changing

Answer (score 0):

Change the `width` attribute on your `svg` element to an absolute value, not a percentage-based one. If you set the width to `100%`, this will scale the *boundaries* of your document instead of scaling the *document*.

```
<svg version="1.1" width="150" height="150" viewBox="800 -50 200 200">
    <path d="M0 107 L220 69 L484 135 L800 82 L800 150 L0 150 Z" />
</svg>
```

Then, apply your width scaling using CSS:

```
svg {
  background: gold;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work for me, instead it gives the same effect (my browser is up to date)

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes to your SVG: I've removed `width` & `height`; this way your svg will scale with the window. Also I've changed your `viewBox` since it looked very strange. Please keep in mind that `viewBox` should look like this: `viewBox(from_x from_y width height)`

```css
svg {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 800 200">
 <path d="M0,107 L220,69 L484,135 L800,82 L800,150 L0,150 Z" />
</svg>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: What i did with the viewBox was to move the parth to the bottom of the element, this way i can really use it to separate diffrent sections of the page, one can be white and one dark, your way doesn't really help me to achive this.